# how to deserialize nested objects in java using object mapper

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, serialization, deserialization, objectmapper

I have a sqs queue , I am polling for messages .

I get the message in following format

```
{
  "Type" : "type_value",
  "MessageId" : "message_id",
  "TopicArn" : "topic_arn",
  "Message" : "{\n  \"contentType\": \"content_type_value\",\n  \"content\": \"content_value\",\n  \"eventName\": \"event_name\",\n  \"eventTS\": 1591235390353\n}",
  "Timestamp" : "2020-06-04T01:49:50.358Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "url"
}
```

when I get this body from SQS using code

`String message = sqs_message_object.getBody()`

Now I create a wrapper class for thie message body as following

```
public class SQSMessage
{
    @JsonProperty("Type")
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty("MessageId")
    private String messageId;

    @JsonProperty("TopicArn")
    private String topicArn;


    @JsonProperty("Message")
    private Message message;

    @JsonProperty("Timestamp")
    private String timestamp;

    @JsonProperty("SignatureVersion")
    private int signatureVersion;

    @JsonProperty("UnsubscribeURL")
    private String unSubscribeUrl;

    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getMessageId()
    {
        return messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId)
    {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public String getTopicArn()
    {
        return topicArn;
    }

    public void setTopicArn(String topicArn)
    {
        this.topicArn = topicArn;
    }

    public Message getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(Message message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getTimestamp()
    {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp)
    {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public int getSignatureVersion()
    {
        return signatureVersion;
    }

    public void setSignatureVersion(int signatureVersion)
    {
        this.signatureVersion = signatureVersion;
    }

    public String getUnSubscribeUrl()
    {
        return unSubscribeUrl;
    }

    public void setUnSubscribeUrl(String unSubscribeUrl)
    {
        this.unSubscribeUrl = unSubscribeUrl;
    }
}
```

And I deserialize the json string in to a SQSMessage object using Object Mapper

```
SQSMessage sqsMessage = null;

                try
                {
                    sqsMessage = objectMapper.readValue(message,SQSMessage.class);
                }
                catch(JsonProcessingException e2)
                {

                }
```

all the fields are getting mapped except for Message field .
because its not just a string but another class.

```
public class Message
{
    private String contentType;
    private Content content;
    private String eventName;
    private Date eventTS;


    public String getContentType()
    {
        return contentType;
    }

    public void setContentType(String contentType)
    {
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }

    public Content getContent()
    {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(Content content)
    {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getEventName()
    {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName)
    {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public Date getEventTS()
    {
        return eventTS;
    }

    public void setEventTS(Date eventTS)
    {
        this.eventTS = eventTS;
    }
}
```

it fils to deserialize the field *Message* .

how do i Map the message field to Messaeg class as mentioned.

The error I get is

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `domain.Message` 
(although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize 
from String value ('{\n  \"contentType\": \"content_type_value\",\n  \"content\": \"content_value\",\n  \"eventName\": \"event_name\",\n  \"eventTS\": 1591235390353\n}')
 at [Source: (String)"{
```

Comment: But Message *is* just a string, because it has double quotes around it. Why is the data on the queue defined like that? Is the code that puts it on the queue also under your control?

Comment: @David Conrad : no I don't control the input to sqs, but since it is strong I can treat the json string and convert it to obiect, I just fail to deal with the inner fields

Comment: Jackson uses JSON. If your input isn't JSON, you'll probably have to deserialize it once, then pull out the message string and run it through Jackson separately.

Comment: yeah , I have tried things ,but no luck so far